# How do I find the equations of line tangent to a unit circle that have a slope of 1?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm supposed to find the equations of the lines tangent to a circle of radius $1$ and centered at the origin that have a slope of $1$.

I know these things: this is a unit circle, the equation for a unit circle is $x^2+y^2=1$, and the slope is the derivative of a point. I've tried taking the derivative of the unit circle equation and setting it equal to $1$:

$${d\over dx}x^2+{d\over dx}y^2-{d\over dx}1=2x+2y$$
$$2x+2y=1$$
I'm not sure what to do with that solution.

I have been attempting to figure out $x_1$ and $y_1$ values to complete the equation:

$$y-y_1=(1)(x-x_1)$$

What am I missing? Am I even going in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $1$ is $0$, not $1$. You also did not do the implicit derivative of $y^2$ correctly. It should be

$$x^2+y^2=1$$
$$\frac d{dx}(x^2)+\frac d{dx}(y^2)=\frac d{dx}(1)$$
$$2x+2y\frac {dy}{dx}=0$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac xy$$

Can you finish from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Implicit differentiation is very new for me, so I'm still not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The tangent to a circle at a given point and its radius through that point are perpendicular.  Now look at the line $y = -x$ and all is now told.